# passive bal tashchis

Tags: halacha, minhag, sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, bal-tashchit-waste

### is passive bal tashchis wrong?

i see jews eat things (sometimes even to the detriment of their health, (because of the amount or quality) so that they will not go to waste

is this a Jewish thing to do (obligation, recommendation...)? source, please

in general, do jews ever need to do something (active) to avoid bal tashchis, when the bal is happening from the inaction of the jew? (obligation, recommendation...)

Comment: Since it comes from the verse לא תשחית את עצה, it apparently seems that only actively wasting is forbidden

Comment: @ba I didn't know that this was the source of the mitzvah. Can you provide a link to that info? It seems that you may have an answer.

Comment: @DanF That's where the phrasing of the prohibition as לא תשחית comes from, doesn't it? A quick search gives Sanhedrin 100b as quoting the verse in full. But I don't know of any place where this is used to prove that passively wasting is permitted, so my comment doesn't answering the question.

Comment: I think we may be dealing with 2 conflicting ideas. On the one hand, there is a "halacha" (I'm not sure if we would call it halacha or an "advisory rule") that one should eat only enough to satisfy his hunger and not stuff himself. On the other hand, one should not "waste food". Thus, it seems that one shouldn't overeat left-over food at a time that he is stuffed just for the sake of not wasting food. If one is not stuffed, he prob. should eat the left-over to avoid לא תשחית , rather than cooking new food. Obviously, one need not ruin his health doing this, esp. if the food is already spoiled.

Comment: Some background - https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%99%D7%AA

Comment: I think this duplicates https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43971. See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48391.

Comment: ```i see jews eat things (sometimes even to the detriment of their health, (because of the amount or quality) so that they will not go to waste``` which  is ironically, (when to the detriment of health), ba'al taschis